# Using Eloquent to remove all rows in a column

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am looking to use a Resource (destroy) post command to remove all rows within one column. The columns name is 'total' and it houses 'bigIntegers' but can be null. This is an SQLITE DB.

I have looked into using "truncate" but it seems that this removes all data from the table. I just want to clear the values within one particular column.

Is there an easy way using Eloquent in 4.2 to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try either with Eloquent:

```
  YourModel::update([ 'total' => null ]);
```

Or the query builder:

```
  DB::table('yourTable')->update([ 'total' => null ]);
```

Here's links to the docs:

- [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)
- [Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates)

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm not on my computer and can't check said solution, in the docs I found the `update()` always preceeded by a `where()` so it ***may*** be mandatory, but you can do `where('id', '>', '0')` or something. Also ***maybe*** `null` will build the actual SQL with nothing on it for a value, resulting in error, so ***maybe*** you actually need `['total' => 'null']`

Comment: How to update all columns as null in laravel? @jselser

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the where close. All rows in the table column total will be set to null.

`Model::update(['total' => null])`;